# How to import a class inside a folder that derives from an abstract class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

In my main directory I have two programs: `main.py` and a myfolder (which is a directory).

The `main.py` file has these 2 lines:

```
from myfolder import Adding 
print(Adding.execute())
```

Inside the myfolder directory, I have 3 python files only: `__init__.py`, `abstract_math_ops.py`, and `adding.py`.

The `__init__.py` file as just one line:

```
from myfolder.adding import Adding
```

The `abstract_math_ops.py` file is just an abstract class with one method:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractMathOps(ABC):
    
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def execute(*args):
        pass
```

The `adding.py` file is:

```
from abstract_math_ops import AbstractMathOps

class Adding(AbstractMathOps):
    
    @staticmethod
    def execute(*args):
        --doing some addition --
```

When I execute `main.py`, I get the error:

```
    ~\myfolder\adding.py in <module>
    ---> 1 from abstract_math_ops import AbstractMathOps
    
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abstract_math_ops '
```

If I put the abstract class inside the adding.py file, I do not get any errors. However, I need to put it in a different file as other python files (i.e. substracting.py, multipying.py) can be created following the footprint of the AbstractMathOps abstract class. Also, that way I do not have everything in a single file.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the entire error message. Which line of code causes the error? None of the code you show here imports from a module named `Calculations`. Please show that part of the code.

Comment: Sorry. I made my problem shorter and forgot to change that part with the entire error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your folder is a package, and you can't import sibling-submodules of a package in the way you're trying to do in `adding.py`. You either need to use an absolute import (`from myfolder.abstract_math_ops import AbstractMathOps`, which works the same anywhere), or use an explicit relative import (`from .abstract_math_ops import AbstractMathOps`, which only works from within the same package).

But if the two modules in your package are really as short as you've shown, maybe you should reconsider making `myfolder` a package at all. You could very easily define all of your classes in single `myfolder.py` file, and it would be easier to make sense of since the classes are so interrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
from .abstract_math_ops import AbstractMathOps
```

You need to add the relative location of the file for the import to work in this case.

Comment: Why If I do print(Adding.execute()) directly from adding.py, I do not need to put .abstract_math_ops and only abstract_math_ops ?

Comment: Printing `execute` is not relevant to the import so no you still need the proper way to import it